# How to change template url in angularjs dynamically from controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

From below angularJS code I want to get parameter `namee` in `templateUrl` please help me to generate dynamic `templateurl`.

```
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.
    when('/AddNewOrder/:namee', { 
        controller: 'AddOrderController',
        templateUrl:'templates/'+namee +'.html';
    }).
    when('/ShowOrders/:name', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/show_orders.html',
    controller: 'ShowOrdersController'
    }).
    otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/AddNewOrder/add_orders'
  });
}]);
```

Comment: @Pamio Note that he is not using ui-router.

Comment: @Subash, Just noted thanks. My sincere apologies, deleted my comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a function as a value to `templateUrl`. The function return value will be the value for templateUrl. Function have access to the url attributes.

Note that the wildcard url name will be the value that you want to access. In your case its `namee`. `console.log(attrs)`, if you want to see details of the `attrs`.

```
$routeProvider.
when('/AddNewOrder/:namee', { 
   controller: 'AddOrderController',
   templateUrl: function(attrs) {
      return 'templates/'+ attrs.namee +'.html';
   }
})
```

Comment: $routeProvider.
      when('/AddNewOrder/:namee', {
       
        controller: 'AddOrderController',
        templateUrl:function($stateParams){
          return 'templates/'+$stateParams.namee+'.html';
        }
    }).

i tried in that way but still got error.

Comment: what do you mean? that will do as well. You can name your variable whatever you want. But as $stateparams is used for ui-router it might confuse with others

Comment: Error: Access to restricted URI denied @Subash

Comment: @ManiDev What is in your url? How is your router fired?

Comment: You get that error, when it can not find the template. console.log(attrs) in the function and see whats the value.

Comment: <li><a href="#/AddNewOrder/add_orders"> Add New Order </a></li>
                <li><a href="#/ShowOrders/show_orders"> Show Order </a></li>